# Lambda expectations in Jmockit

Tags: java, junit, lambda, jmockit

I have a I/F

`public interface NumberIF {
    public Integer getNumber();
}`

and when I try to call the following func;

`public void func(NumberIF data)`

I use the following way with lambda

`func(() -> 5)`

The problem is that I cannot match the above function with the JMockit expectations...

`new Expectations() { { someclass.func(() -> 5); }`

For `Callable<T>` objects, `.equals` method is always comparing some sort of id number rather than the literal objects stored in them. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JMockit` matches arguments in expectation/verifications blocks using the `equals` method (which by default compares the object ids).

In your example, the object created by the lambda expression (`() -> 5`) does not implement the `equals` method hence the object ids are compared.

Bottom line: if you really want to compare `Callable<T>` objects, you either have to implement `equals` in the concrete implementations or you need to make sure you are using the same instance in your expectations block as in your 'production code' call.